# Excel VBA: change x axis value as desired

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating charts with origin(100,0) i.e, x axis value=100. At first I used,

```
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MajorUnit = 10
```

and I got the x axis ... 70,80,90,100,110,120,130....etc

I thought it would be better if I had axis values as ...60,80,100,120,140... etc. So I edited my code as follows,

```
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MajorUnit = 20
```

But now I am getting ...70,90,110,130... etc.

How can I get my x axis as ...60,80,100,120,140...?

Comment: I think you need to set `MinimumScale` in addition to the `MajorUnit`.  `MinimumScale` sets the lower bounds of the Axis and `MajorUnit` sets the distance between tick marks.  `ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 60`

Comment: These `Chart` properties are best learned by recording some macros to see what VBA is generated when you make the change in Excel.  @PortlandRunner is correct about needing to change the `MinimumScale`.